# In iOS4 applicationWillEnterForeground may get called before applicationDidEnterBackground and it makes problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiapplicationdelegate

In iOS 4, if I close & re-open my app rapidly then (after *applicationWillResignActive* invocation) there is a chance for   *applicationWillEnterForeground*  to be get called well before the  *applicationDidEnterBackground*  and results in  **a black blank screen**  as because the app entered into background state immediately after the foreground state.

this is the order it was printed in the console:

**** 1. applicationWillResignActive** 

 **2. applicationDidEnterBackground** 

 **3. applicationWillEnterForeground** 

 **4. applicationDidBecomeActive** 

 **1. applicationWillResignActive** 

 **3. applicationWillEnterForeground** 

 **2. applicationDidEnterBackground ****

How to handle such scenario? and to make sure that application delegate methods are executed in the correct order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 1: FILE A BUG! It sounds like this is a real problem; it should get fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Keep a counter for switches and ignore switches that happen in the wrong order.  Something like this:

```
-(void) handleSwitchToBackground {
  if ( myState == 0 ) { /* do background stuff */ }
  myState += 1;
}

-(void) handleSwitchToForeground {
  myState -= 1;
  if ( myState == 0 ) { /* do foreground stuff */ }
}
```

If foreground happens before background, neither method does anything.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this would avoid the black blank screen problem as because the app entered into background state immediately after the foreground state. And this state transition is completely under the control of SDK or OS, when user taps the home button or app icon.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well.

Only in my case it sometimes happens when my app receives local notification.